# set new file name when using google drive.files.copy

Tags: node.js, google-drive-api

I'm using google drive apiv3 to copy a spreadsheet into a folder on google drive. The documentation states the "name" property should be used to set the title of the new sheet. I'm using this, but newly created sheets are named "Copy of {titleOfSheetToCopy}".

request:

```
app.get('/new', function (req, res) 
{
    var drive = google.drive({version:'v3', auth: jwt_client});

    var copyRequest = {
        name: 'im a copy',
        fileId: 'idOfSheetToClone',
        parents: ['idOfDestinationFolder'],
    }

    drive.files.copy(copyRequest,  function(err, response){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            res.send('error');
            return;
        }
        res.send(response);
    });
});
```

response:

```
{
"config": {
    "url": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/-----/copy?name=im%20a%20copy&parents=---",
    "method": "POST",
    "headers": {
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip",
        "User-Agent": "google-api-nodejs-client/0.7.2 (gzip)",
        "Authorization": "---",
        "Accept": "application/json"
    },
    "params": {
        "name": "im a copy",
        "parents": [
            "---"
        ]
    },
    "responseType": "json"
},
"data": {
    "kind": "drive#file",
    "id": "---",
    "name": "Copy of _template",
    "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet"
},
"headers": {
    "alt-svc": "quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"46,43\",h3-Q050=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q049=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q048=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=\":443\"; ma=2592000",
    "cache-control": "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate",
    "connection": "close",
    "content-encoding": "gzip",
    "content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
    "date": "Mon, 25 Nov 2019 05:37:01 GMT",
    "expires": "Mon, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT",
    "pragma": "no-cache",
    "server": "GSE",
    "transfer-encoding": "chunked",
    "vary": "Origin, X-Origin",
    "x-content-type-options": "nosniff",
    "x-frame-options": "SAMEORIGIN",
    "x-xss-protection": "1; mode=block"
},
"status": 200,
"statusText": "OK"
}
```

can see that response.data.name shows the default naming instead of "i'm a copy".

Any direction would be appreciated. Thanks

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/copy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- You want to copy a file using the method of Files: copy in Drive API v3.
- You want to achieve this using googleapis with Node.js.
- You have already been able to use Drive API.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer?

#### Modified script:

In this modification, `copyRequest` and `drive.files.copy()` were modified as follows.

```
var copyRequest = {  // Modified
  name: "im a copy",
  parents: ["idOfDestinationFolder"]
};

drive.files.copy(
  {  // Modified
    fileId: "idOfSheetToClone",
    requestBody: copyRequest  // or resource: copyRequest
  },
  function(err, response) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.send("error");
      return;
    }
    res.send(response);
  }
);
```

#### Note:

- If an error occurs, please use the latest version of googleapis.

#### Reference:

- [Files: copy](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/copy)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: This solved it and your assumptions are correct. I see the name property should be specified in the request body. Thanks

Comment: @justin Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Comment: @Tanaike Thank you so much for this--I was pulling my hair out.  Do you know a good reference site for the Google nodejs API?  Everything at https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/googleapis/latest/index.html just leads to boilerplate, nothing I've found details all the APIs for (say) drive.files and what their parameters are.  And the reference you give above only shows the REST API, not the nodejs API

Comment: @Jabberwock Thank you for your comment. When I use Google APIs using various languages, I always check each repository of googleapis for each language. For example, when I use Google APIs using Node.js, I check https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client . I confirm how to use the Google APIs by checking the source script. Because the official library for Google APIs is often updated and I want to check the latest script. And also, we can also see the discussions for the library at the issue in GitHub. If this was not useful for your situation, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the new file name as the `name` property of a `resource` attribute. The documentation says, that `name` property is to be passed as a property of a `requestBody` attribute, but that did not work in my case.

Solution:

```
drive.files.copy(
  {
    fileId: "idOfSheetToClone",
    resource: { name: "filename"}
  },
  function(err, response) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.send("error");
      return;
    }
    res.send(response);
  }
);
```